# Get list of features correlated with target variable

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I am trying get the list of features of my dataset greater than 0.15
It code let me do it but I have as result a serie panda that I cant retrieve the column names in a list 
to after do the drop of them in my dataset.
I appreciate your help.

```
# Remove highly correlated features
cor = features_binario.corr()
#Correlation with output variable
cor_target = abs(cor["G3"])

#Selecting highly correlated features
relevant_features = cor_target[cor_target>0.15]

first_column = relevant_features.iloc[:,0]
first_column
```

I am getting this error, IndexingError: Too many indexers

```
Var: relevant_features
school_GP      0.177564
school_MS      0.177564
higher_no      0.251587
higher_yes     0.251587
course_math    0.168394
course_por     0.168394
age            0.153819
Medu           0.184047
Fedu           0.183627
failures       0.390165
G1             0.701693
G2             0.717439
G3             1.000000
Name: G3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What is `print (relevant_features.info())` ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Series`, so no columns.

For all values by conditions use:

```
relevant_features = cor_target.index[cor_target>0.15]
```

Comment: I got   0.17756387716348085 it is value

Comment: Its close I got "school_GP"

Comment: @Fernando - what is expected output?